# When can one find a canonically conjugate operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, canonical-conjugation

Suppose one is given a self-adjoint operator $A$ acting on an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Under what conditions can one find an operator $B$ such that $[A,B] = i$? And if this is possible, how does one construct $B$?

For simplicity, assume that $H \simeq L_2(\mathbb{R})$ and that $A = A(X,P)$ is a function of the position operator $X$ and momentum operator $P$.

What I ultimately want to know is the following. Given a self-adjoint operator $A(X,P)$, by Stone’s theorem we know that $A(X,P)$ generates a one-parameter unitary group $U(t) = e^{-iA(X,P) t}$. What I want to know is if there is a self-adjoint operator (observable) $B(X,P)$, such that $U(t)$ generates translations of $B(X,P)$. And how to find $B(X,P)$ given $A(X,P)$. I know the the condition for $A(X,P)$ to generate translations of $B(X,P)$ is that these operators must satisfy the canonical commutation relation $[A,B] = i$, and hence the reason for phrasing the question as I did. This is analogous to how $P$ generates translations in $X$, that is, $e^{-i Px} \left|x_0\right\rangle = \left|x+x_0\right\rangle$.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by conjugate operator. The definition you wrote is too vague. The answer by @ACuriousMind is valid under some further requirements in the domains of the (symmetric) operators and their essential selfadjointness. If the space is finite dimensional the answer is trivially that no conjugate operators exist.

Comment: Sorry for typos, I'm using my phone...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you for your replies! I've edited the question above, I hope this helps clarify things. I want the domain of the operators to be the state space $S(\mathcal{H}) := \{\rho \in S(\mathcal{H})  | \rho \geq 0 , {\rm tr} \rho = 1 \}$. I suppose in the case of pure states this would correspond to the Schwarz space on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I agree that for a finite dimensional Hilbert the answer is trivial, although one could probably reformulate the question and look for approximately conjugate operators.  Something like the first equation, in the first column, on the second page of this article by A. Peres titled "Measurment of time by quantum clocks" <https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.12061>.

Answer (score 6):

There is a conjugate operator if and only if there is a unitary operator $U$ such that $UAU^\dagger = X$. This is a consequence of the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem#Uniqueness_of_representation) - all representations of the canonical commutation relations are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: Agreed! But given $A$ how does one know if such a $U$ exists? And how does one find $U$?

Comment: @e4alex I've appended the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understand you, if and only if the spectrum of $A$ is equal to the spectrum of $X$, which coincides with the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$, then there exists such a unitary $U$. This implies that for $B$ to exist then the spectrum of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: However, consider A = P^2, the spectrum of which coincides with the positive real line $\mathbb{R}_+$, which is not equal to the spectrum of $X$. And yet $A = P^2$ is canonically conjugate to the operator $B = -\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{P} X + X \frac{1}{P} \right)$. In this case the spectrum of $A$ is not equal to the spectrum of $X$.

Also, what if the spectrum of $A$ is degenerate? How is the unitary constructed?

Comment: @e4alex Ah, unbounded operators, they never play nice. My claim only holds for bounded operators...

Comment: In terms of degeneracy, I think the clearest example is $A=X^3-X$. I don't know whether it has canonical conjugates, though.

Comment: The spectrum argument is false. There is no general connection between the spectra of the two can. conjugate operators. And @ACuriousMind it is important to state that those representations which are unitarily equivalent must be irreducible, i.e. in a sense the representation space must be maximal.

Comment: Stone von Neumann theorem, in addition to the absence of non-trivial proper closed subspaces invariant under $P$ and $X$, requires that $X^2+P^2$ is essentially self adjoint on a common dense invariant domain.

Comment: The form of SvN theorem quoted in the answer is not  the appropriate one for the considered issue, since it uses one parameter groups of unitary operators, instead here generators of those unitary groups are considered. The condition I wrote above about rhe sum of the squared operstors assures the existence of those unitary groups.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, but I think the physical essence of the problem can be better grasped by considering the classical analogue of OP's question:

**Q:** When does a *classical* observable, $A$, have a conjugate observable?

First a bit of background on classical Hamiltonian mechanics [1]. On the phase space $T^*M=\{(q,p)\}$ (the co-tangent bundle of some configuration space $M=\{q\}$), observables are taken to be the real-valued, *smooth*, *single-valued* functions defined *globally* on phase space. (The emphasized adjectives will be important for us.) Each observable $A(q,p)$ defines a Hamiltonian flow $\Phi^A_t$ on phase space (via Hamilton's equations with Hamiltonian $A$). Along the integral curves of this flow, the value of any observable $B(q,p)$ changes as
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\dot B=\{A,B\},
\end{equation}
where $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ denotes the Poisson bracket. A pair of observables $A,B$ for which $\{A,B\} = 1$ identically are said to be conjugate to each other. In this case $A$ is also said to be “the” generator of translations in $B$ (and vice versa); because, by \eqref{eq1}, the value of $B$ changes monotonically at unit rate along the integral curves of the flow $\Phi^A_t$.

Returning to question **Q**. The key is to consider the flow lines of $\Phi^A_t$. Suppose there existed a flow line $\gamma$ that closed on itself (as would happen, e.g. in the vicinity of any local extrema of $A$). Then $A$ could not have a conjugate observable $B$; because by going once around $\gamma$ the value of $B$ would have to increase by a finite amount equal to the period of the orbit ($\Delta B=\oint_\gamma \{A,B\}dt=\oint_\gamma 1dt=T_\gamma>0$), so $B$ would have to be either discontinuous or multi-valued; and hence not an observable. More generally: $A$ has no conjugate observable if $\Phi^A_t$ has any integral curves bound to a finite-volume region of phase space. (Hint: use the Poincaré recurrence theorem and a similar argument as above.)

Notice that for an observable $A$ which fails to have a conjugate observable, it is still possible to speak of a *locally-defined* conjugate “quantity”, $B$, which satisfies $\{A,B\}=1$ but fails to satisfy the stringent definition of a bona fide observable. (This much is guaranteed by the Carathéodory-Jacobi-Lie theorem [2].) This is illustrated on the 2D phase space $T^*\mathbb{R}$ by the observable $I=\frac12(q^2 +p^2)$ (the Hamiltonian for the simple harmonic oscillator); whose conjugate quantity $φ=\arg(q+ip)$ (the phase of oscillation for the sho) either fails to be globally continuous, or else fails to be single-valued (depending on one’s choice of definition). A similar example, this time on the 6D phase space $T^*\mathbb R^3$, is $L_z=xp_y-yp_x$ (the $z$-component of angular momentum), whose conjugate quantity $\theta=\arg(x+iy)$ suffers from the same affliction.

Returning to OP's question regarding *quantum* observables: I'd just like to point out a link between classical observables, $A$, whose values become quantized (discretized) upon quantization, and those for which the flow $\Phi^A_t$ has closed orbits—that is, in view of the above: a link between quantum observables with discrete spectra and observables lacking a conjugate. The link is easiest to see in the case of classical observables that are completely integrable (as in the Liouville-Arnold theorem [1]). On the one hand, such observables admit action-angle coordinates; so the flow consists *entirely* of closed orbits. On the other hand, by the [Einstein–Brillouin–Keller method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Brillouin%E2%80%93Keller_method) of "old quantum theory", the quantum observable's spectrum is discrete.

[1] V. I. Arnol’d, Mathematical methods of classical mechanics, 2nd ed. (Springer-Verlag, 1982).

[2] P. Libermann and C.-M. Marle, Symplectic geometry and analytical mechanics, Vol. 35 (Springer Science & Business Media, 2012).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughtful reply. As you point out, it is interesting to think about the corresponding question in classical theory. Since asking the question, I have encountered the theory of covariant positive operator valued measures, which can be thought of as satisfying morally equivalent properties to the canonical commutation relations. Thanks again!